# How do I get MongoDB to recognize a number as a double?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation

I am trying to save the number `3.0` into a schema that expects a double. Unfortunately it seems that Mongo interprets it as an integer and I get a validation failure error.

My validator looks like this:

```
avgRating: {
  bsonType: 'double',
  minimum: 1,
  maximum: 5
},
```

My query looks like this:

```
await db.collection('products').updateOne(
    {_id: productId},
    {
      $set: {
        avgRating: 3.0
      }
    },
);
```

I have checked with other numbers like `3.00001` or `4.2` and they work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I missed the [`Double`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/double.html) class included in the Node.js driver which causes the number to be treated properly:

```
const {Double} = require('mongodb');

await db.collection('products').updateOne(
  {_id: productId},
  {
    $set: {
      avgRating: Double(3.0)
    }
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your validator to the following:

```
avgRating: {
  bsonType: ["double"],
  minimum: 1,
  maximum: 5
},
```

I think the lack of `[]` makes MongoDB treat it as `int` or something else, causing this behavior.